# Joining two Array<['string', 'string']> throws compiler warning

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to join two Array like this:

```
const param = null
const optionsHeaders: Array<['string', 'string']> = param || []
const sesHeaders = [
    ['X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', 'config-set']
]
const headers: Array<['string', 'string']> = [...optionsHeaders, ...sesHeaders]
console.log(headers)
```

The result is as expected:

```
[
  [
    "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET",
    "config-set"
  ]
]
```

But the TypeScript compiler is complaining:

```
Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type '["string", "string"][]'.
  Type 'string[]' is missing the following properties from type '["string", "string"]': 0, 1

const headers: Array<['string', 'string']> = [...optionsHeaders, ...sesHeaders]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `: string` = all possible strings, `: 'string'` = only the string `'string'`. Yes, values can be types!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the type on sesHeaders as, by default an array literal `[ 'foo', 'bar']` will have an inferred type of `string[]` and not `[string, string]`.

Also, your `'string'` don't need the single quotes because, as @nino-filio points out, constant values can be types too so by saying `'string'` you're saying "only a string of value 'string'".

```
type Headers = [ string, string ][];

const param = null
const optionsHeaders: Headers = param || []
const sesHeaders: Headers = [
    ['X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', 'config-set']
]
const headers: Headers = [...optionsHeaders, ...sesHeaders]
console.log(headers);
```